# redhat - compile ffmpeg - how to link with liblame/x264 when they're installed locally

Tags: ffmpeg, compilation, redhat, lame, x264

I've managed to install ffmpeg, a basic build using

```
./configure --disable-debug --disable-network --disable-ffserver --disable-ffplay --prefix=/export/home/userid/bin/ffmpeg
```

Now I've installed liblame and x264 to /export/home/userid/bin and tried to compile ffmpeg as follows:

```
./configure --disable-debug --disable-network --disable-ffserver --disable-ffplay --prefix=/export/home/userid/bin/ffmpeg --enable-libmp3lame  --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl
```

And I get the error

```
ERROR: libmp3lame not found
```

How can I tell configure to look for things in /export/home/bin?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

compile using --enable-cflags and --extra-ldflags